# Fast way to "down-scale" a three-dimensional tensor index

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

This is a bit twiddling question for C or C++. I am running GCC 4.6.3 under Ubuntu 12.04.2.

I have a memory access index `p` for a three-dimensional tensor which has the form:

```
p = (i<<(2*N)) + (j<<N) + k
```

Here `0 <= i,j,k < (1<<N)` and `N` some positive integer.

Now I want to compute a "down-scaled" memory access index for `i>>S, j>>S, k>>S` with `0 < S < N`, which would be:

```
q = ((i>>S)<<(2*(N-S))) + ((j>>S)<<(N-S)) + (k>>S)
```

What is the fastest way to compute `q` from `p` (without knowing `i,j,k` beforehand)? We can assume that `0 < N <= 10` (i.e. `p` is a 32 bit integer). I would be especially interested in a fast approach for `N=8` (i.e. `i,j,k` are 8 bit integers). `N` and `S` are both compile time constants.

An example for `N=8` and `S=4`:

```
unsigned int p = 240407; // this is (3<<16) + (171<<8) + 23;
unsigned int q = 161; // this is (0<<8) + (10<<4) + 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `q = ((i>>S)<<(2*(N-S))) + ((j>>S)<<(N-S)) + (k>>S)`? Otherwise you may not have enough bits.

Comment: Completely true and I fixed the question. Thanks!

Comment: Are `N` and `S` constant? I.e. does it affect speed of downscaling function if it computes complicated expressions involving `N` and/or `S`?

Comment: N and S are compile time constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward way, 8 operations (others are operations on constants):

```
M = (1<<(N-S)) - 1;                     // A mask with S lowest bits.
q = (  ((p & (M<<(2*N+S))) >> (3*S))    // Mask 'i', shift to new position.
     + ((p & (M<<(  N+S))) >> (2*S))    // Likewise for 'j'.
     + ((p & (M<<     S))  >>    S));   // Likewise for 'k'.
```

Looks complicated, but really isn't, just not easy (to me at least) to get all the constants correct.

To create formula with less operations, we observe that shifting numbers by `U` bits to the left is the same as multiplying by `1<<U`. Thus, due to multiplication distributivity, multiplying by `((1<<U1) + (1<<U2) + ...)` is the same as shifting to the left by `U1`, `U2`, ... and adding everything together.

So, we could try to mask needed portions of `i`, `j` and `k`, "shift" them all to the correct positions relative to each other with one multiplication and then shift result to the right, to the final destination. This gives us three operations to compute `q` from `p`.

Unfortunately, there are limitations, especially for the case we try to get all three at once. When we add numbers together (indirectly, by adding together several multipliers), we have to make sure that bits can be set only in one number, else we'll get a wrong result. If we try to add (indirectly) three properly shifted numbers at once, we have this:

```
iiiii...........jjjjj...........kkkkk.......
 N-S      S      N-S      S      N-S
.....jjjjj...........kkkkk................
 N-S  N-S      S      N-S
..........kkkkk...............
 N-S  N-S  N-S
```

Note that farther to the left in the second and third numbers are bits of `i` and `j`, but we ignore them. To do this, we assume that multiplication works as on x86: *multiplying two types `T` gives a number of type `T`, with only the lowest bits of the actual result (equal to the result if there is no overflow)*.

So, to make sure that `k` bits from the third number do not overlap with `j` bits from the first, we need that `3*(N-S) <= N`, i.e. `S >= 2*N/3` which for `N = 8` limits us to `S >= 6` (just one or two bits per component after shifting; don't know if you ever use that low precision).

However, if `S >= 2*N/3`, we can use just 3 operations:

```
// Constant multiplier to perform three shifts at once.
F = (1<<(32-3*N)) + (1<<(32-3*N+S)) + (1<<(32-3*N+2*S));
// Mask, shift/combine with multipler, right shift to destination.
q = (((p & ((M<<(2*N+S)) + (M<<(N+S)) + (M<<S))) * F)
     >> (32-3*(N-S)));
```

If the constraint for `S` is too strict (which it probably is), we can combine the first and second formula: compute `i` and `k` with the second approach, then add `j` from the first formula. Here we need that bits don't overlap in the following numbers:

```
iiiii...............kkkkk.......
 N-S   S   N-S   S   N-S
..........kkkkk...............
 N-S  N-S  N-S
```

I.e. `3*(N-S) <= 2*N`, which gives `S >= N / 3`, or, for `N = 8` much less strict `S >= 3`. The formula is as follows:

```
// Constant multiplier to perform two shifts at once.
F = (1<<(32-3*N)) + (1<<(32-3*N+2*S));
// Mask, shift/combine with multipler, right shift to destination
// and then add 'j' from the straightforward formula.
q = ((((p & ((M<<(2*N+S)) + (M<<S))) * F) >> (32-3*(N-S)))
     + ((p & (M<<(N+S))) >> (2*S)));
```

This formula also works for your example where `S = 4`.

Whether this is faster than straightforward approach depends on architecture. Also, I have no idea if C++ guarantees the assumed multiplication overflow behavior. Finally, you need to make sure values are unsigned and *exactly* 32 bit for the formulas to work.

Answer (score 0):

does it meet your requirements?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

uint32_t to_q_from_p(uint32_t p, uint32_t N, uint32_t S)
{
   uint32_t mask = ~(~0 << N);
   uint32_t k = p &mask;
   uint32_t j = (p >> N)& mask;
   uint32_t i = (p >> 2*N)&mask;
   return ((i>>S)<<(2*(N-S))) + ((j>>S)<<(N-S)) + (k>>S);;
}

int main()
{
   uint32_t p = 240407;

   uint32_t q = to_q_from_p(p, 8, 4);

   std::cout << q << '\n';

}
```

if you assume that N always is 8 and integers are little endian then it can be

```
uint32_t to_q_from_p(uint32_t p, uint32_t S)
{
   auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&p);
   return ((ptr[2]>>S)<<(2*(8-S))) + ((ptr[1]>>S)<<(8-S)) + (ptr[0]>>S);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for compatibility, for N = 8 you can get i, j, k like that:

```
 int p = .... 
 unsigned char *bytes = (char *)&p;
```

Now `k` is `bytes[0]`, `j` is `bytes[1]` and  `i` is `bytes[2]` (I found little endian on my machine). But I think the better way is sth. like that (we have N_MASK = 2^N - 1)

```
 int q;
 q = ( p & N_MASK ) >> S;
 p >>= N;
 q |= ( ( p & N_MASK ) >> S ) << S;
 p >>= N;
 q |= ( ( p & N_MASK ) >> S ) << 2*S;
```